# Error from Firebase Project URL: Adding www causes "Your connection is not private"

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a firebase project that loads properly unless I type the url to my project with `www.` in front.

---

**This works**:

```
https://myproject.firebaseapp.com
```

---

**This returns an error**:

```
https://www.myproject.firebaseapp.com
```

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
>   www.myproject.firebaseapp.com (for example, passwords, messages, or
>   credit cards). [Learn more](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6098869) NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

---

**Attempt to resolve**

- I followed the "[Learn More](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6098869)" in the error above and it seems that
  the error might be that firbase by default sets up
  `myproject.firebaseapp.com` but not `www.myproject.firebaseapp.com`.
- I then checked the firebase app in the hosting console (i.e. https://console.firebase.google.com/project/myProjectNameHere/hosting/main)
  and it does show only the non-`www` version, but adding the `www` version here does not seem possible since I do not own the `firebaseapp` domain so I cannot add the provided TXT file at this point to the DNS records.

---

**Does anyone know why this is occurring and how to get the project to load when `www.` is added to the url?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported.

To give some technical detail, wildcard SSL certificates are only valid for a single level; so `*.firebaseapp.com` but not `*.*.firebaseapp.com`. In addition, this is (in my estimation) entirely unnecessary as it simply makes the URL longer.

What I **would** encourage you to do is purchase a domain name for use with your Firebase Hosting site, and connect it. Read "[Connect a Custom Domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain)" in our docs for more info.